# Reading from a file and writing to another using Awk

Tags: awk

There are two tab delimiter text files. My aim is to change File 1 so that corresponding values in the 2nd column of File 2 will be substituted with zeros in File 1.

To visualize,

File 1:

```
AA 0
BB 0
CC 0
DD 0
EE 0
```

File 2:

```
AA 256
DD 142
EE 26
```

File 1 - Output:

```
AA 256
BB 0
CC 0
DD 142
EE 26
```

I wrote below but as you can see I give the value of 1st row of File 2 by hand. I want to achieve this task automatically. What should I do?

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {if($1 == "AA") $2="256";print}' test > test.tmp && mv test.tmp test
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1, a[$1]+0}' file2 file1
```

Comment: I wrote the old and long -else if version- of the command to compare the outputs. As I saw, this command does not change the input file. I think there should be a little error. I will try to find it. Thanks. P.S. 2nd column may not be the last column. I have no idea the problem is about this detail or not.

Comment: this command is in no way intended to change the input file. You should already know that because the command you posted in your question has the additional steps needed to write the output of this command back to the input file. I don't know what "2nd column may not be the last column" means.